# Set timeout not working in jQuery sequence

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery function written below. What I would like to happen in the function is for the .fadeToggle to disappear the unwanted elements BEFORE the selected div applies the pod expanded class to itself. For some reason whenever i add the setTimeout function wrapped around toggleClass podexpanded the toggleClass expand part does not work. without the setTimout the function works fine but i need to delay the second part of the code until the first part is finished.

Here is my code:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.portfoliopod', function(){

jQuery('.portfoliopod').not(jQuery(this)).fadeToggle(500);

setTimeout(function () {
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('podexpanded');
   }, 600);

jQuery(this).toggleClass("portfolioimagezoom");

jQuery(this).children(".portfoliopodmessage").toggleClass('hidepod');

setTimeout(function () {
    jQuery(".portfolioimage").toggleClass('portfolioimagelarge');

}, 400);
});
```

Comment: You can't use `this` inside of the `setTimeout`.  When the function is ran, `setTimeout` sets `this` to `window`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before any setTimeout calls, add:

```
 var th = jQuery(this);
```

then in the timeout functions us th instead of jQuery(this) like this:

```
th.toggleClass('podexpanded');
```

Answer (score -1):

fadeToggle's third argument allows for you to supply a function that executes after fadeToggle's animation completes.

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.portfoliopod', function()
{

    jQuery('.portfoliopod').not(jQuery(this)).fadeToggle(500, 'swing', function() 
    { 
         $(this).toggleClass('podexpanded');
    });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() 
{ 

  $("#test").hide();
  
  $("#test").fadeToggle(500, 'swing', function() 
  {
    $(this).addClass('a_new_class').html('Update to this text after fadein in original div.');
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">My text</div>
```

Comment: will not work for the same reason the timeouts are not working. using "this" inside of a function refers to that function.

Comment: Using $(this) refers to the original selection element that fadeToggle was applied too, not the function being called. There is absolutely no reason to use setTimeOut in this case. I added an example code snippet.

Comment: Please see the example I edited into the answer. It demonstrates what I am saying perfectly. 'this' referes to the object invoking the method, not the method itself. This, my friend, is basic javascript.